# Does Microsoft Clarity for SharePoint (Web Analytic Tool) - Is it possible to drilldown to user level e.g Top Visitors

Tags: web-analytics

I would like to use this tool for SharePoint Online sites.
Is it possible to drilldown to user level analytics e.g Top Visitors of a site/page etc..

Thanks in Advance